# How to get sensor data into the beacon advertising data?

Tags: android, ios, sensors, beacon

How to use MetaTracker(MbientLab) beacon mode to send the sensor data into the advertising data?

Answer (score 0):

Except the beacon info, you can not broadcast other data from beacon device.